# How to get jquery working for all items in the loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am using the following code in the wordpress and also using the lightbox form plugin.

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=9&post_type=packages') ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
     ...
      ...
    <span class="package-book">
    <div id="text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".package-book a").click(function() {
            var $temp = $('#text').html();
            $('#book-title').val($temp);
        });
     });

     </script> 

       <?php echo do_shortcode("[formlightbox text='Book Now' title= 'welcome'][contact-form-7 id='383' title='Booking Form'][/formlightbox]"); ?>
         or consider this <a title="welcome" class="fl_box-1" href="#">Book Now</a>
      </span>  
       <?php endwhile; ?>
       <input type="text" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="book-title" value="" name="PackageTitle">
```

`I am using contact us 7 plugin` and have created a form booking form which has been embedded in lightbox form.

Actually `when book now anchor tag is clicked` the book now `form gets popped up on the screen.`

`I want that input type text with id  book-title` should be `filled with current package title<?php the_title(); ?>.`

`The above jquery works for first package only.`Please please help me so that it will work for all the package.

Comment: IDs must be unique on each page (in fact document as iframes are exception based on context)

Comment: I am not getting it.please explain

Comment: You are echoing <div id="text"> in php loop, which is not good as i stated before, ID must be unique. But your input "#book-title" seems not in the loop, so maybe its not your problem here. For sure, what is not good is setting script tag inside your PHP while loop. Put it outside the loop and see whats going on.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the input with id "#book-title" is not in the loop. Can you please suggest some alternative ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `$` here:

```
jq(".package-book a").click(function(){
```

instead write this:

```
$(".package-book a").click(function(){
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery anywhere?

Comment: No, I am loading this jquery in the same file(template file)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

1. Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file else in the html head section
2. Be sure that you've included the datatale script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
3. Check whether jQuery is included properly and once only.
4. Watch out for jQuery conflicts. There is some other library which is overridding $, so your code is not working because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore. You can use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable $.
5. Check whether all the required class and ids area attached.